# Provisioner local-exec: 'always_run' trigger doesn't work as expected

Tags: terraform

In my terraform I have mysql module as follows:

```
# create ssh tunnel to RDS instance
resource "null_resource" "ssh_tunnel" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ssh -i ${var.private_key} -L 3306:${var.rds_endpoint} -fN ec2-user@${var.bastion_ip} -v >./stdout.log 2>./stderr.log"
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
}

# create database
resource "mysql_database" "rds" {
  name = var.db_name
  depends_on = [null_resource.ssh_tunnel]
}
```

When I'm adding new module and running `terraform apply` first time it works as expected.
But when `terraform apply` running without any changes I'm getting an error:

```
Could not connect to server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
```

If I understand correctly, provisioner "local-exec" should execute script every time due to the trigger settings. Could you explain how should it works properly?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what's happening?

Comment: I've just implemented this solution https://registry.terraform.io/modules/flaupretre/tunnel/ssh/latest
instead of using 'null_resource'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've implemented this solution https://registry.terraform.io/modules/flaupretre/tunnel/ssh/latest instead of using `null_resource`.

Comment: Hi, I am stuck in this same situation, i am unable to make the `tunnel` work using module also, can you please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this happens because your first `local-exec` creates the tunnel in the background (-f). Then second execution fails because the first tunnel still exists. You do not close it at all in your code. You would have to extend your code to check for an existence of tunnels and maybe properly close them when you are done using them.

Comment: Hi Marcin, Can you please help me in solving this ?

Comment: @user280960 Hi. Solve what? Did you make a new SO question specific to your issue?

Comment: Hi Marcin, i am facing this same problem, even i created a SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706390/terraform-ssh-tunnel-bastion, i am unable to make ssh tunnel work in CI/CD pipeline.